# Customized ArrayListAdapter.clear() is not working

Tags: android, listadapter

I'm using ListView to show search results. I have a Coustomized arrayListAdapter which returns a list of Objects. This is working fine. My listView is showing just a TextView nothing else.

But I want to clear the List when I again go to the search page. I have tried

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    mListAdapter.clear();
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.onResume();
}
```

And the SearchListAdapter

```
public class SearchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chapter>
{
public Context context;
private static String searchText = null;

public SearchListAdapter(Context context)
{
    super(context, R.layout.favorite_tab_list_view_row);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++)
        getSearchChapters().remove(i);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.clear();
}

private ArrayList<Chapter> getSearchChapters()
{
    ArrayList<Chapter> chapter = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
    if (searchText != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < DataStore.getHierarchicalChapters()
                .getSubChapters().size(); i++)
        {
            String str = DataStore.getHierarchicalChapters()
                    .getSubChapters().get(i).getChapterContent()
                    .toLowerCase();
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(searchText.toLowerCase());
            Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

            while (mat.find())
            {mat.start()); //
                chapter.add(DataStore.getHierarchicalChapters()
                        .getSubChapters().get(i)); // the
                break;
                // occurrance
            }
            if (DataStore.getHierarchicalChapters().getSubChapters().get(i)
                    .hasSubchapters())
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < DataStore.getHierarchicalChapters()
                        .getSubChapters().get(i).getSubChapters().size(); j++)
                {
                    str = DataStore.getHierarchicalChapters()
                            .getSubChapters().get(i).getSubChapters()
                            .get(j).getChapterContent();
                    mat = pat.matcher(str);
                    while (mat.find())
                    {
                        chapter.add(DataStore.getHierarchicalChapters()
                                .getSubChapters().get(i).getSubChapters()
                                .get(j));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    return chapter;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return getSearchChapters().size();
}

@Override
public Chapter getItem(int position)
{

    return getSearchChapters().get(position);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_tab_list_view_row, parent,
                false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.chapterName = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.favoriteChapterTextViewId);

        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

    viewHolder.chapterName.setText(getSearchChapters().get(position)
            .getTitle());

    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView chapterName;
}

public static void setSearchText(String searchText)
{
    SearchListAdapter.searchText = searchText;
}
}
```

My question is, How can I clear the list ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to `override` the method `clear()` for your custom `ArrayAdapter` and manually empty the list of objects on which your adapter is based(and don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`). This is what the default `ArrayAdapter` is doing.

**EDIT :**

Your code will never work now because your custom adapter gets its data from calling the method `private ArrayList<Chapter> getSearchChapters()` which **rebuilds** the adapter's data **every time** the method is called(for example every time the adapter calls getView() it will rebuild the data). My advice is to make a private field in your adapter :

```
ArrayList<Chapter> data;
```

and then in your adapter's constructor initialize it by calling the method `getSearchChapters()` :

```
data = getSearchChapters();
```

Then you can override the method `clear()`:

```
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        data.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.clear();
    }
```

Also you can't call `clear` from `onResume()` because your list will never get populated with data(the adapter will be empty). I didn't understand when you want to clear the list so i can't tell you when to call the `adapter.clear()`. You can make a test with a button that calls `clear()` to see if this clears the adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I got the point :) Just set the searchText to null in onResume.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the ArrayList that the Adapter is using then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on Adapter